# Visibility of a button in cgridview based on the equality of two models fields

Tags: yii, visibility, cgridview

i have this array that represent the data for a button in a CGridView widget in YII.

```
array(
        'Button' =>
        array(
                'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/image.png',
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("controller/action", array("column"=>$data->column))',
                'visibile'=>'$visibile',
        ))
```

I need $visibile to be true or false based on this function:

```
if (array_key_exists(0 , Table::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('column' => $model->column)))){
$visible = true;    
}
else {
$visibile = null;
}
```

where Table::model is not the same model of the grid.
How can i modify the visibility of the button based on the equality of the value in the record of this model and the model of the view?

I hope my question was clear, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in Yii

```
array(
    'Button' =>
    array(
        'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/image.png',
        'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("controller/action", array("column"=>$data->column))',
        'visibile'=>function($index, $data) {
            // the logic, where $data is the model for that row
            // ...

            // return true(visible) or false(invisible)
        },
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following might work for you:

```
array(
    'Button' =>
    array(
            'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/image.png',
            'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("controller/action", array("column"=>$data->column))',
            'visibile'=>"return array_key_exists(0 , Table::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('column' => $model->column)));",
    ))
```